# Atualizar planilha por outra planilha

Tags: r, atualização, planilha

Tenho dois dataframes com as colunas idênticas, sendo um a base de dados e outro atualizações mensais. Preciso atualizar a base de dados com essas atualizações mensais. Pensei no seguinte código:

```r
if(A$Empreendimento == B$Empreendimento)

  {

  A$`POT [MW]`<-B$`POT [MW]`
  A$STATUS<-B$STATUS
  A$`VALIDADE ATUAL`<-B$Validade
  A$RESOLUÇÃO<-B$Resolução

}
```

Mas recebo se seguinte mensagem de erro

```r
Error in A$Empreendimento : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

A ideia seria atualizar pelo campo Empreendimentos, se tiver o mesmo empreendimento nas duas planilhas, você atualiza os campos da planilha A com base na planilha B

Edit1: dput(head(A, 10))

```r
structure(list(Empreendimento = c("J1", "AMB 108", "Água Branca", 
"Foz do Apiacás", "Prata", "Araguanã", "Couto Magalhães", "Mortes 2", 
"Santa Isabel", "Torixoréu"), Tipo = c("UHE", "UHE", "UHE", "UHE", 
"UHE", "UHE", "UHE", "UHE", "UHE", "UHE"), Processo = c(NA, NA, 
NA, "48500.004786/2006-80", "48500.001486/2009-35", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "48500.000218/2000-22"), `POT [MW]` = c(140.5, 11.7, 73, 
275, 12.4, 960, 150, 310.4, 1087, 408), `Curso D'Água` = c("Acari", 
"Amambaí", "Amapari", "Apiacás", "Aporé", "Araguaia", "Araguaia", 
"Araguaia", "Araguaia", "Araguaia"), UF = c("AM", "MS", "AM", 
"MT", "GO/MS", "MA/PA/TO", "GO/MT", "PA", "PA/TO", "GO/MT"), 
    Empreendedor = c(NA, NA, NA, "Empresa de Pesquisa Energética - EPE", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), STATUS = c("Eixo Disponível", "Eixo Disponível", 
    "Eixo Disponível", "Aceito", "Eixo Disponível", "Eixo Disponível", 
    "Eixo Disponível", "Eixo Disponível", "Eixo Disponível", 
    "Eixo Disponível"), Ato = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 1242, 3246, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Data = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 1273104000, 1481846400, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Resolução = c(NA, NA, NA, "395/1998", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "395/1998"), Validade = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

dput(head(B, 10)

```
 structure(list(Num = c("5", "8", "9", "26", "27", "30", "29", 
"39", "54", NA), Processo = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "48500.006323/2014-14", 
"48500.005280/2014-41", NA, NA, NA), Tipo = c("UHE", "UHE", "UHE", 
"UHE", "UHE", "UHE", "UHE", "UHE", "UHE", "UHE"), Empreendimento = c("A17PA118 (Bacuri)", 
"A26PA184 (Miriti)", "A29PA208 (Touré)", "A34PA250 (Samuã)", 
"A38PA100", "A41PA008 Panamã", "A41PA008 Panamã", "Açaipé B", 
"Água Branca I", "Água Clara"), `POT [MW]` = c("225.7", "140.5", 
"186.3", "104.1", "177.8", NA, "870.4", "831.1", "73", "32.799999999999997"
), `Curso D'Água` = c("Paru", "Paru", "Paru", "Paru", "Paru", 
"Paru", "Paru", "Jari", "Amapari", "Verde"), `Bacia do rio` = c("PARU", 
"PARU", "PARU", "PARU", "PARU", "PARU", "PARU", "JARI", "ARAGUARI", 
"PARANÁ"), `Região Hidrográfica` = c("AMAZÔNICA", "AMAZÔNICA", 
"AMAZÔNICA", "AMAZÔNICA", "AMAZÔNICA", "AMAZÔNICA", "AMAZÔNICA", 
"AMAZÔNICA", "AMAZÔNICA", "PARANÁ"), UF = c("PA", NA, "PA", NA, 
"PA", "PA", "48500.005280/2014-42", NA, NA, "MS"), Empreendedor = c("Omega Energia Renovável", 
"Omega Energia Renovável", "Omega Energia Renovável", "Omega Energia Renovável", 
"Omega Energia Renovável", "Enel Brasil S.A.", "Zeta Energia S.A.", 
NA, "Hydros Engenharia", "Minas PCH S.A."), STATUS = c("EIXO DISPONÍVEL", 
"EIXO DISPONÍVEL", "EIXO DISPONÍVEL", "EIXO DISPONÍVEL", "EIXO DISPONÍVEL", 
"REGISTRO ATIVO", "REGISTRO ATIVO", "EIXO DISPONÍVEL", "EIXO DISPONÍVEL", 
"ACEITO"), DESPACHO...12 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "4744", "4104", 
NA, NA, "539"), `DATA DE 
PUBLICAÇÃO...13` = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1418169600, 1413158400, NA, NA, 1425427200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), RESOLUÇÃO = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"395/1998", "395/1998", NA, NA, "412/2010"), `VALIDADE ATUAL` = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1481500800, 1476403200, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), DESPACHO...16 = c("1272 - Aprov", 
"1272 - Aprov", "1272 - Aprov", "1272 - Aprov", "1272 - Aprov", 
NA, "1272 - Aprov", "4757 - Aprov", "157 - Aprov", NA), `DATA DE 
PUBLICAÇÃO...17` = structure(c(1398211200, 
1398211200, 1398211200, 1398211200, 1398211200, 590803200, 1398211200, 
1323302400, 955929600, 1425427200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), `SITUAÇÃO ESTUDO/ANEEL` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Inventário:Empresa de Pesquisa Energética - EPE", 
NA, NA), CODNW = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), E = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 259490.614, 259490.614, NA, NA, NA), N = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 9884644.072, 9884644.072, NA, NA, NA), FUSO = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 22, 22, NA, NA, NA), `Energia Firme MWmed` = c(124.3, 
77.3, 102.5, 57.3, 97.8, 478.7, 478.7, 457.11, 22, 24.9), `VAZÃO MLT

m³/s
(a)` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "677.77", NA, NA, NA), `Tempo Enchimento
(meses)
(a)` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Área total do Reservatório (km²)` = c("31.25", 
"37.049999999999997", "22.23", "51.89", "349.37", "185.02", "185.02", 
"293.39999999999998", "120.81", "31.08"), `Área Alagada (km²)` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "-", NA, NA, NA, NA), `Potência /área (MW/km²)` = c(0.138458130261409, 
0.263701067615658, 0.119323671497585, 0.498463016330452, 1.96496062992126, 
NA, 4.70435628580694, 0.353026109974732, 1.65493150684932, 0.947560975609756
), `Margem do Rio Amazonas` = c("ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", 
"ME", "ME", "ME", NA, NA), `Reservatório
a Fio d'Água / Regularização
` = c("Fio d'Água", 
"Fio d'Água", "fio d'agua", "Fio d'Água", "Fio d'Água", "Regularização", 
"Regularização\r\n Em 10/2015 o IBAMA arquivou o pedido de licenciamento. (ESEC do Jari)", 
"Regularização", "Regularização", "Fio d'Água"), `Nível dágua 
máximo normal (m)` = c("160", 
"208", "240", "268", "118", NA, "100", "86", "100", "310.89999999999998"
), `Depleção 
(m)` = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "6", "6", "3.45", 
"8.5", "0"), `Queda de Referência` = c(39.9, 23.28, 31.04, 17.46, 
19.49, NA, 88.96, 53.04, NA, NA), `Volume Útil 
(hm³)` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", NA, "1059.5800000000004", "916.65", "777.255", 
"0"), `Energia Armazenável - Curto prazo / Longo Prazo (MWmed)` = c("0", 
NA, "0", "0", "0", "306", "306", "246", NA, NA), `Origem do Orçamento
` = c("Estudos de Inventário", 
"Estudos de Inventário", "Estudos de Inventário", "Estudos de Inventário", 
"Estudos de Inventário", "Estudos de Inventário / Reavaliação da SEG", 
"Estudos de Inventário / Reavaliação da SEG", "Estudos de Inventário", 
"Estudos de Inventário", "Estudos de Inventário"), `Data Base do OPE Original, S/ Conexão` = structure(c(1314835200, 
1314835200, 1314835200, 1314835200, 1314835200, 1480550400, 1480550400, 
1228089600, 880934400, 1377993600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), `Custo Implantação na data base OPE Original, S/ Conexão (s/JDC) 
[R$ x 10³]` = c(1016371.31787006, 
794210.237796087, 889947.354731503, 662617.059897763, 997238.13643928, 
3382790, 3382790, 2207621.82366692, 122780.475241675, 209490.255146927
), `Fator de Atualização do do Custo para Data de Referência` = c(1.39860629739097, 
1.39860629739097, 1.39860629739097, 1.39860629739097, 1.39860629739097, 
0.989168913267202, 0.989168913267202, 1.60042554770711, 4.46840051117328, 
1.23757485316344), `Custo Implantação sem Conexão (s/JDC) na Data de Referência 
[R$ x 10³]` = c(1421503.32566063, 
1110787.44003399, 1244685.97467392, 926740.392731701, 1394743.53762241, 
3346150.70811116, 3346150.70811116, 3533134.36627231, 548632.338332, 
259259.87175263), `Data Base do Custo de CONEXÃO` = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1480550400, 1480550400, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `Custo de CONEXÃO (s/JDC)  (R$ x 10³) - Para os Estudos de inventário: Valor conexão Estimado pela EPE` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 203287, 203287, NA, NA, NA), `Fator de Atualização do Custo de CONEXÃO para Data de Referência` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.989168913267202, 0.989168913267202, NA, NA, 
NA), `VALOR TOTAL, incluindo conexão, na Data de Referência (s/ JDC)
 (RS x 10³)` = c(1421503.32566063, 
1110787.44003399, 1244685.97467392, 926740.392731701, 1394743.53762241, 
3547235.88898251, 3547235.88898251, 3533134.36627231, 548632.338332, 
259259.87175263), `Fator de Ajuste decorrente da origem do Orçamento` = c(1.35, 
1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35), `CAPEX - Valor atualizado para cálculo da Tarifa (R$ x 10³)` = c(1919029.48964185, 
1499563.04404588, 1680326.06580979, 1251099.5301878, 1882903.77579026, 
4788768.45012639, 4788768.45012639, 4769731.39446762, 740653.6567482, 
350000.826866051), `Tarifa Estimada (R$/MWh)` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `ICB
(R$/MWh)` = c(207.193174371653, 260.059956906871, 
220.065748818707, 292.657506797305, 257.680662472674, NA, 130.608898001293, 
136.162775727809, 454.538990073241, 191.258479309137), `CAPEX 
PNE 2050
(S/ JUROS)
R$ x 1000` = c(1810034.8517104, 
1414392.73690711, 1584889.00653672, 1180041.1430994, 1775960.96099259, 
4516781.96624151, 4516781.96624151, 4498826.1534714, 698586.936259741, 
330121.917445491), `CAPEX 
PNE 2050
(S/ JUROS)
R$/kW` = c(8019.64932082587, 
10066.8522199794, 8507.18736734685, 11335.6497896196, 9988.53183910346, 
NA, 5189.31751636203, 5413.09848811383, 9569.68405835261, 10064.6926050455
), `
PDE2029
DEZ-18
CAPEX 


(S/ JUROS)
R$ x 1000` = c(2069076.5989858, 
1616812.46686747, 1811709.17914439, 1348921.82474842, 2030126.24957458, 
5163197.74740263, 5163197.74740263, 5142672.20228217, 798564.668965547, 
377367.062050402), `OBSERVAÇÃO SEG...52` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `TERRAS INDIGENAS (TI)` = c("NÃO", 
"NÃO", "NÃO", "NÃO", NA, NA, NA, "NÃO", "SIM", NA), QUILOMBOLAS = c("NÃO", 
"NÃO", "NÃO", "NÃO", NA, "NÃO", "NÃO", "NÃO", NA, NA), `UNIDADE CONSERVAÇÃO (UC)` = c("FLOTA DO PARU", 
"FLOTA DO PARU E REBIO DO MAICURU", "FLOTA DO PARU E REBIO DO MAICURU", 
"FLOTA DO PARU E REBIO DO MAICURU", "FLOTA DO PARU", "FLOTA DO PARU e ESEC DO JARI", 
"FLOTA DO PARU e ESEC DO JARI", "UC, RDS e ESEC", "SIM", NA), 
    `Classificação Socioambiental` = c("Interfere em UC de US", 
    "Interfere em UC de PI", "Interfere em UC de US", "Interfere em UC de PI", 
    "Interfere em UC de US", NA, "Interfere em UC de PI", "Interfere em UC de PI", 
    "Interfere em UC de PI", "Não interfere em UC, TI e TQ"), 
    `Avaliação Processual  
Cenário 1` = c("2027", "2030", "2027", 
    "2030", "2027", NA, "2030", "2030", "2030", "2027"), `Avaliação Processual  
Cenário 2` = c("2027", 
    "2030", "2027", "2030", "2027", NA, "2030", "2030", "2030", 
    "2027"), `Órgão Ambiental` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "IBAMA", 
    NA, NA, NA), `Resumo Situação` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "sem movimentação", 
    "ESTUDO DE VIABILIDADE PARALIZADO AGUARDANDO RESPOSTA DA ANEEL QUANTO A POSSIBILIDADE DE REDUZIR O NA CONFORME INVENTÁRIO VER SITUAÇÃO ATUAL \r\nem 04/2015 o desenvolvedor(Omega)  solicitou o TR ao IBAMA. Em 10/2015 o IBAMA respondeu que devido a sobreposição do reservatório da UHE com a ESEC do Jari arquivou o pedido de licenciamento.Em 10/16 a Omega encaminha carta para ANEEL informando o arquivamento do licenciamento e solicitando revogar o despacho de aprovação do inventário e emitir novo despacho aprovando a alternativa de divisão de queda proposta pelo desenvolvedor onde a UHE Panamã não interfere com a ESEC e nem com a FLOTA do Paru\r\n•  Processo arquivado no Ibama por interferir na ESEC. (info MME - mar/16)\r\n•  TR não emitido. EIA não iniciado.", 
    NA, NA, NA), `Afeta UC?` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `Trativas UC *2` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Afeta TI?` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `Tratativas TI` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `Tem TR?  *3` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Emissão do TR` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `EIA/RIMA +ECI *4` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `Atendimento a demandas judiciais` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), LP = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `DATA SMA LEILÃO GERAÇÃO` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `CONEXÃO 
SIN` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `SITUAÇÃO
 SIN` = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), GET = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), LEILÃO = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), `PDE 2026` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), `PDE 2027` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `PDE 2029` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "sim", NA, NA, 
    NA), `OBSERVAÇÃO SEG...78` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Estudo não disponível na EPE", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), `Incluído no PNE?` = c("SIM", "SIM", "SIM", 
    "SIM", "SIM", NA, "SIM", "SIM", "SIM", "SIM")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 10))` para cada uma das planilhas `A` e `B`? E o que é `UHE`? A mensagem de erro acontece quando corre que linha de código?

Comment: O erro está dizendo que `A` é um vetor atômico e, por isso, o operador `$` não é aplicável. Ai está a fonte do seu erro.Verifique o objeto `A` com funções como `str()` ou `class()`.

Comment: @TomásBarcellos `A` é capaz de ser uma matriz. O operador `$` não é válido mas as matrizes têm colunas e por vezes aparecem usuários que cometem o erro de pensar que o acesso se faz da mesma forma que com data.frames.

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic Editarei a pergunta com  as funções que você pediu para eu utilizar. Também editei o UHE.
No caso eu chamei de planilhas, mas são dois dataframes

Comment: O problema na verdade é o seguinte:
Tenho duas planilhas em Excel, uma de base e uma mensal.
Quero atualizar a base automaticamente com os dados da mensal, mas só nos casos em que a coluna empreendimento, presente das duas planilhas, estiverem iguais.

Comment: Em `A` tem `Empreendimento` igual a `"Água Branca I"` e em `B` é só `"Água Branca"` São o mesmo?

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic são diferentes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código seguinte deve resolver o problema da pergunta.

1. Para cada linha de `A`,
2. Determina a linha de `B` que tem o mesmo `Empreendimento`.
3. Se tiver encontrado uma e só uma, atualiza as colunas da questão.

Isso é feito num ciclo `for`.

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(A))){
  j <- which(B$Empreendimento == A$Empreendimento[i])
  if(length(j) == 1){
    A[["POT [MW]"]][i] <- B[["POT [MW]"]][j]
    A[["STATUS"]][i] <- B[["STATUS"]][j]
    A[["VALIDADE ATUAL"]][i] <- B[["Validade"]][j]
    A[["RESOLUÇÃO"]][i] <- B[["Resolução"]][j]
  }
}
```

Comment: Aparentemente funcionou, rodou sem dar erros, vou verificar a base resultante para conferir se atendeu o que eu precisava. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!